# Twitter oauth cant get callback

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth

Hello I am trying to make a twitter API. I am using oAuth for it to authenticate myself. The problem is it doesnt do anything i got the same as in the guide which im following. Am i making a mistake in the configuration or in my code?

```
<?php
    require("src/TwitterOAuth.php");
    session_start();

    $twitteroauth = new TwitterOAuth("CONSUMER KEY", "CONSUMER SECRET KEY");
    $request_token = $twitteroauth->getRequestToken("http://127.0.0.1:22119/twitter_login.php");

    $_SESSION['oauth_token'] = $request_token['oauth_token'];
    $_SESSION['oauth_token_secret'] = $request_token['oauth_token_secret'];

    if($twitteroauth->http_code=200)
    {

        $url = $twitteroauth->getAuthorizeUrl($request_token['oauth_token']);
        header('Location:'. $url);
    }

    else
    {

        die('Something wrong happened.');
    }


?>
```

Here screenshot of my twitter app settings: http://i.imgur.com/De2XzWU.png

The guide im following: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-authenticate-users-with-twitter-oauth--net-13595

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

first of all you need add new application to your twitter dev profile , and you need to specify the callback url , than if you're using a php mvc framework you need to go to your controller in twitter action you need to add the following:

```
 // TWITTER APP KEYS
    $consumer_key = 'something you get from twitter dev';
    $consumer_secret = 'other thing you get from twitter dev';
// CONNECTION TO THE TWITTER APP TO ASK FOR A REQUEST TOKEN
    $connection = new TwitterOAuth($consumer_key, $consumer_secret);
    $request_token = $connection->oauth("oauth/request_token", array(
        "oauth_callback" => "http://something/otherthing"
    ));
 // TAKING THE OAUTH TOKEN AND THE TOKEN SECRET AND PUTTING THEM IN COOKIES (NEEDED IN THE NEXT SCRIPT)
    $oauth_token = $request_token['oauth_token'];
    $token_secret = $request_token['oauth_token_secret'];
```

if you want you can put some variables in the cookies for a father use :

```
 setcookie("token_secret", " ", time() - 3600);
    setcookie("token_secret", $token_secret, time() + 60 * 10);
    setcookie("oauth_token", " ", time() - 3600);
    setcookie("oauth_token", $oauth_token, time() + 60 * 10);
```

than you need to ask twitter to authorize your app

```
 // GETTING THE URL FOR ASKING TWITTER TO AUTHORIZE THE APP WITH THE OAUTH TOKEN
    $url = $connection->url("oauth/authorize", array(
        "oauth_token" => $oauth_token
    ));
```

and the last thing you have to do is to render the url , basically this means that after the user give his approval we need to redirect him to another page where we could use more feature of twitter Oauth :

```
// REDIRECTING TO THE URL
    header('Location: ' . $url);
}
```

please take a look abraham's twitter Oauth it's possible to upload it using composer.json:

```
{
"type": "package",
"package": {
    "name": "abraham/twitteroauth",
    "description": "Twitter oauth",
    "version": "dev-dev",
    "keywords": ["Twitter API", "Twitter oAuth"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "authors": [
      {
        "name": "Abraham Williams",
        "email": "abraham@abrah.am"
      }
    ],
    "require": {
      "php": ">=5.3.2"
    },
    "autoload": {
      "files": ["twitteroauth/OAuth.php"]
    },
    "source": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth",
        "reference": "origin/dev"
    }
}}]
```